# How to overcome this assembly incompatibility causing a compiler error?

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, cross-platform

I am using Visual Studio to maintain a C project designed for an embedded platform. I am trying to use the Visual C compiler to build the project, going as far as it can before stopping on errors, and when ready, rebuild it with the target toolchain. This way I can use the IDE's superior capabilities over the native, outdated target IDE.

Naturally, not all the code features of the native compiler can be understood by the Visual C compiler, but I managed, using command line Defines and Undefs, and using the native compiler's system header files, to make a pretty satisfying progress.

What I am stuck at now is using inline assembly. In some of the system header files there are code pieces that use inline assembly, in the form of:

```
#define GET_COUNT(count) \
    do {
        __asm volatile ("r2 = CYCLES;  \n" \
                        "r1 = CYCLES2; \n" \
                        "[%0]   = r2;  \n" \
                        "[%0+4] = r1;  \n" \
                        : : "p" (&(count)) \
                        : "r1", "r2" );    \
    } while (0)
```

I am looking for a way to make the MS C compiler ignore the `c2400` error regarding the assembly instructions. It can be by somehow automatically commenting out the `__asm` call, or renaming it to a keyword which will make the compiler ignore it. However, the one requirement is that *there is no change made to the source code of the system header itself*.

---

**UPDATE 1:** A usage example of this macro is in another system header file:

```
static clock_t clock(void)
{
  _cycle_t _cnt;
  _GET_COUNT( _cnt );
  return  (clock_t) _cnt;
}
```

This code generates the mentioned error.

So, I created a file containing a definition for a temporary function:

```
void temp_func(char *a)
{
    return;
}
```

and in the project options I defined `volatile=` and `__asm=temp_func`. Then I used the **Forced Include File** option to include that file. My thought was that this way, the original `__asm volatile ("blah");` will be mapped to `temp_func("blah")` call and thus will have no effect on the build.

However, now I get the following error on the line with the macro usage:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ':'

Comment: One technique is to use say `#define MSVC` and then provide alternative code using `#ifdef MSVC ... #else ... #endif`. Are you allowed to change, indeed add another version of `GETCOUNT()`? I presume you are using some kind of a wrapper in MSVC where you can make a `#define`, seeing as you mention using `#define` and `#undef`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Thanks. As mentioned in the original question, I am not allowed to change the system headers themselves. The problematic macro is being used in another system header and the error is generated there. See my update to the question.

Comment: What I used to do, was to put everything that is platform-specific in a separate .c file or files. Then when I wanted to test/prove the code on a PC, write other versions that patch as best as possible. Then it would be just a different file included in the project, and the target code wasn't littered with work-arounds.

Comment: Sorry, you said you weren't allowed to change one file (singular).

Comment: Why not just provide a different version of the header file, rather than edit the one you have? Is this an artificial restriction?

Comment: @WeatherVane - well, these are system files, which are deeply nested in `#include` directives. I don't see how I can replace a specific header and make the preprocessor take it instead of the original one. Remeber, I cannot modify the embedded compiler installation itself, as I need a working build environment.

Comment: By replacing it with another of the same name, with alterations to the tricky bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane - this was actually a good idea. I copied the file to my project space and it has precedence in the include search path. I am playing with this now...

Comment: @WeatherVane - A good idea indeed. I replaced the original definition with an empty `do..while` and now it passes that point! You make it an answer and I'll approve and rep you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique is to use say `#define MSVC` and then provide alternative code using `#ifdef MSVC ... #else ... #endif`.

Another way is to put everything that is platform-specific in a separate .c file or files. Then when I wanted to test/prove the code on a PC, write other versions that patch as best as possible. Then it would be just a different file included in the project, and the target code wasn't littered with work-arounds.

So then you just provide alternative versions of whatever files need to be different, without touching the source code.

Comment: The solution was to copy the header to the local project space, such that it had precedence in the search path, then make the changes to the copied file.

Answer (score 0):

The header is using AT&T format assembly and Microsoft compilers will only accept Intel format assembly. Normally you would have to rewrite the code in the header in Intel format.

Theoretically, you might be able to compile the headers to object code using GCC and then include them as static libraries in your project.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not the format but rather the processor architecture (i.e., ISA).

Comment: From this help page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w77ed359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, my understanding is that the problem is the instruction itself, but anyway I cannot change the source code, as mentioned in the question.